# If Exists with Insert statement Not going to Else part

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

My SQL query is like below

```
if exists(select 1 from mytable2 T,mytable M where T.bookid=M.bookid)
 begin
  insert into books(col1,col2)
  select col1,col2 from library
 end

else
 begin
  insert into booknotfound 
  select col1,col2 from library
end
```

say Library is a source table. I'll insert in books table only if BookId is present in "mytable" otherwise I want to insert in "booknotfound" table.the above query inserting records in books table but not in "booknotfound" table. So what I want to do is I am looking for bookid for each record in "mytable2" Is is possible this way?

Comment: Why is everything in `library` getting dumped into either of those tables?

Comment: library table is imported from some another DB if I have the book id in my table i insert the book details in BOOKS table else in BOOKNOTFOUND table.

Comment: If the else branch was not hit, the condition was true. That's a fact. Execute the condition query manually to find out why it returned rows. I don't see any filter in it, just a join condition.

Comment: What its doing is it checks for bookid if not exits it moves on to next record instead of going to else part.I have 4 records in mytable2 2 records do not meet the condition so they should go to booknotfoundtable but its not the case now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something else than what you've written/expect you've written. (I would guess).

What you're checking for is not each row in an interation, but all books at once. Remember, SQL operates on SETs of data (which can be a single row, or multiple).

So what you're doing is asking

If this returns 1

```
select 1 from mytable2 T,mytable M where T.bookid=M.bookid
```

Then insert ALL elements from Library into Books.

If it returned 0, insert ALL elements from Library into Books not found.

What I think you're after is either doing a cursor based operation (not adviceable), or doing two different setwise operations such as

```
INSERT col1, col2 INTO books FROM liberary WHERE <INSERT YOUR WHERE CLAUSE>
INSERT col1, col2 INTO booknotfound FROM liberary WHERE <INSERT YOUR WHERE CLAUSE>
```

The specifics of your WHERE clause is difficult to deduce from what you've written as I fail to see any link between library and your "mytable" and "mytable2"
(are you missing some information?)

My guess is that you're after the books not in library from mytable should be put into not found and those that are in library should be in books?

Comment: got me right. I think curor is the solution for me. The approach you have suggested that I should use two insert queries it will again iterate

Comment: It shouldn't iterate depending on how you build your where clause. It is what I meant by SQL working on sets of data instead of just the single row. 

I'm unsure how your structure is, but if we assume that you in Mytable have a list of books you want to verify against "Library", then a simple join between those two tables will give you all that exists or the ones that does not exists, and you can then work on that entire set in one go. It's where SQL is strong. The cursor based solution would properly be worse performance, but might be easier to comprehend to begin with.

Comment: I resolved my problem using 2 queries as you suggested. Its better than using a cursor ofcourse. Thanks.